# Getting the value of an array derived from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of products the secretary can choose. These products are looked up from the product table and an array was used to display them.

The secretary can select up to any number of the products by checking the checkboxes corresponding to the product. When submitted, the checked products are then displayed in a new page.

Supposedly, the secretary would be able to input the amount of boxes, weight, date of production, and price for each selected product. As I have to insert the information to the table, I'm wondering how I'll be able to do it with an array whose value is not know to me. I've seen examples of inserting arrays into tables, but not arrays that were derived from a table.

EDIT: Added in the code.

```
    $products = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProdName FROM product");
    $numofprod = mysqli_num_rows($products);

    $i = 0;
    while($i < $numofprod) {
        while($row = $products->fetch_assoc()){
        $prodlist = $row["ProdName"];

                echo "<input type='checkbox' class='prodlist' name='check_list[]' id='prodlist";
                echo "$i'";
                echo " value='";
                echo $prodlist;
                echo "'>";
                echo $prodlist;
                echo "</input>";

             $i++;
            }   
    }
```

// upon submitting, it will execute the code below

```
            if(isset($_POST['add_purchase_submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
            if(!empty($_POST['prodlist'])){
            echo "<table><tr><th></th><th> Boxes </th> <th> Weight </th> <th> Price </th>  <th> Production Date </th> </tr>";

            // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
            foreach($_POST['prodlist'] as $selected){                   
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $selected;
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='ppbox' size='10'>";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='ppweight' size='10'>";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='ppprice' size='10'>";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='ppproducion' size='15' placeholder='MM/DD/YY'>";
            echo "</td><td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }
```

I also realized I have an error in the names in the second form...

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
  echo '<input name="array['.$i.']"'>;
}
```

This gives an amount of inputs abed on you array. Later you can read that as a array in php again:

```
foreach($_POST['array'] as $entry){
  .. do things ..
}
```

Only a basic scatch, but this shows how you can use arrays as names for inputs. The same way you could use them for checkboxes or other felds you need.

Comment: I added in the code I was using. Am I even the right track?

Comment: How I understand what you want to do I'd add in name-arrays in the second part aswell: `name='ppbox[$i]'`. Thus you can read out there arrays lateron aswell.